# How to extract data from a CipherInputStream?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I decrypt a file on the internal memory, as follows:

```
CipherInputStream cip = new CipherInputStream(context.openFileInput("filename"), cipher);
```

How can I get the decoded result and convert it, for example, to the string?

---

**UPDATE:**

File, which is stored in the phone's internal memory is encrypted json-file. The method should read this file, decrypt and return the result as a string:

```
public String getJSON() {
            String jsonString = "";

    try {
            String algorithm = "DESede";
            jsonString = "";
            SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
            DESedeKeySpec kspec = new DESedeKeySpec(readKey().getBytes());
            SecretKey key = skf.generateSecret(kspec);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            CipherInputStream cip = new CipherInputStream(context.openFileInput("filename"), cipher);

            // here I have to get the result of decoding and write it to the jsonString

            cip.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonString;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us more code. Make explicit what you want to accomplish as well.

Comment: @owlstead , the post is updated.

Comment: I guess you need to provide an IV as well. With regards to `CipherInputStream` is works just like [any other stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html). But beware that it shoves cryptographic related exceptions under the carpet (!).

Comment: I don't see you call `doFinal()`.

Comment: @dcow You mean [`CipherInputStream.doFinal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html#doFinal%28%29)?

Comment: @owlstead I meant [Cipher.doFinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal()) but I guess the input stream handles that.

Comment: You have to read from the CipherInputStream until EOF.